# creation of tools or website for application deployment task

Tags: django, python-3.x, automation

i’m python beginner and i want to make python tools for below requirement OR wanted to complete below task with Django website.
Task: I have 1 application on server and want to deploy that application to all ~400 machines(mac os client machines ) now i wanted to know is it possible to automate this task by making some GUI Application(using python) OR python website(Django)?
If yes then how to handle offline machines and how to post IP of each machines in one file and from there how to how to distinguish offline machine .What could be prototype?

Comment: Could you specify what the script should do? Is the script running on all 400 machines or only on one server?

Comment: Hi Jakob, I want to install application in 400 machines so file is already there and I want to automate this task... And  my question is this possible to do with gui app or website(Django). If yes then what will be logic...? How to get real time changing ip and also while deployment few machines may be offline so need to get details of offline machines.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not get what your actual goal is.. So have got a Python script running on all machines that installs another program?
btw, what do you mean by machines, and what is the operating system on them?

Comment: O.S is mac os and right now we are doing deployment with the help of Linux scripting... Machines =400, server =application which need to deploy.

Comment: I guess I personally can't help you then, but as far as I understand, there are two main tasks: connecting a lot of scripts from different computers via VPN and installing a mac program with Python. I would suggest you to ask the first task as a new question here, I am sure you will find a solution for the second one in the internet.